# How to perform operations on images in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, bitwise-operators

I am trying to complete a challenge where i use an equation to construct a new image (d) from other images. Then i must get the flag in the image (d). The given images are a.png, b.png c.png and y.png and they can be found here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1bZOm_0apr5ZmaRNf9R5UVIEmtMuYSphn?usp=sharing

The equation: d = y - 21a - 3b + 41c

My current code

```
from PIL import Image

imagey = Image.open('y.png')
imagea = Image.open('a.png')
imageb = Image.open('b.png')
imagec = Image.open('c.png')
size = width, height = imagey.size

new = Image.new('RGB', size)

imgy = imagey.load()
imga = imagea.load()
imgb = imageb.load()
imgc = imagec.load()
data = new.load()

for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        they = imgy[x, y]
        thea = imga[x, y]
        theb = imgb[x, y]
        thec = imgc[x, y]

        new_color = ((int(they[0])) & ~(int((21 * thea[0])) ^ int((3 * theb[0])) ^ int(~(41 * thec[0]))),
                     (int(they[1])) & ~(int((21 * thea[1])) ^ int((3 * theb[1])) ^ int(~(41 * thec[1]))),
                     (int(they[2])) & ~(int((21 * thea[2])) ^ int((3 * theb[2])) ^ int(~(41 * thec[2]))))
        data[x, y] = new_color

new.save('final.png')
new.show()
```

Comment: I don't understand. Your formula is simple multiplication and addition. What has that got to do with bitwise operations?

Comment: if you would convert `Pillow image` to `numpy array` or you would use `OpenCV` or `imageio` to load image (and get directly `numpy array`) then  you could do directly `imagey - 21*imagea - 3*imageb + 41*imagec`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would convert `Pillow image` to `numpy array` or you would use `OpenCV` or `imageio` to load image (and get directly `numpy array`) then you could do
directly

```
new = imagey - 21*imagea - 3*imageb + 41*imagec
```

**Result:**

Not ideal but much better than with your code.

It can be problem with `overflow`. It may create array with `8bits` values and calculations can gives `16bits` or `32bits` values which can be reduced to `8bits` in every calculation.

[image]

**Full working code:**

```
import imageio

imagey = imageio.imread('y.png')
imagea = imageio.imread('a.png')
imageb = imageio.imread('b.png')
imagec = imageio.imread('c.png')

new = imagey - 21*imagea - 3*imageb + 41*imagec

imageio.imwrite('final.png', new)

# --- imageio doesn't have function to display it ---

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(new)
plt.show()
```

---

**EDIT:**

If I use `OpenCV` then I get ideal result

[image]

**Full working code:**

```
import cv2

imagey = cv2.imread('y.png')
imagea = cv2.imread('a.png')
imageb = cv2.imread('b.png')
imagec = cv2.imread('c.png')

new = imagey - 21*imagea - 3*imageb + 41*imagec

cv2.imwrite('final.png', new)

# --- show window with image and wait for press any key ---

cv2.imshow('Image', new)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

**EDIT:**

**By the way:** version which converts `PIL Image` to `numpy array` and later it converts back to `PIL Image` - but it gives the same result as `imageio`.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

imagey = Image.open('y.png')
imagea = Image.open('a.png')
imageb = Image.open('b.png')
imagec = Image.open('c.png')

arr_y = np.array(imagey)
arr_a = np.array(imagea)
arr_b = np.array(imageb)
arr_c = np.array(imagec)

arr_new = arr_y - 21*arr_a - 3*arr_b + 41*arr_c

new = Image.fromarray(arr_new)

new.save('final.png')
new.show()
```

---

**BTW:**

If I check images on Linux using program `file` then it shows that `b.png` and `c.png` are `JPEG`, not `PNG`.

```
$ file b.png

b.png: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, resolution (DPI), 
density 300x300, segment length 16, 
Exif Standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=0], baseline, 
precision 8, 960x640, components 3
```

---

I found that `cv2.imread()` gives little different values for `c.png`(which is `JPG` file) then other modules - and I don't mean that `cv2` gives colors in `BGR` instead of `RGB` - and later this gives correct result. Probably `cv2` uses different C library to read `JPG`.